# What are we missing out by using Tableau online and not server?

Tags: tableau-api

We are using Tableau Online as our BI platform, we currently have 150 users. What features on Tableau server that we are missing out on?

One of the things I recall is that we couldn't implement a font we wanted to use on Tableau Online but that would have been something very easy if we had server.

What other things we are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope these resources would help you to understand the pros and cons better

https://community.tableau.com/thread/193134

http://www.marquisleadership.com/messages/tuesdays-with-tableau-tableau-server-vs-tableau-online

https://www.interworks.com/blog/bfair/2014/08/26/tableau-online-vs-tableau-server-5-things-consider